# Limits involving Trig functions

Tags: limits, asymptotics

I want to find the limit of $f(x)=(x^3+x)\sin x+(x^2+x^{1/3}) \cos x$ as $x \to \infty$. Let $f \sim g$ mean that $f$ is asymptotic to $g$, as usual. We have, as $x \to \infty$, both $x^3+x \sim x^3$ and $x^2+x^{1/3} \sim x^2$. Therefore, I would guess that $f(x)\sim x^3\sin x+x^2 \cos x$ as $x \to \infty$. What is confusing me is the use of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ because of the obvious issue encountered in the fraction $\sin x/ \cos x$.

Comment: I am confused by your posting.  Taking the 1st sentence in your posting at face value, as $~x \to \infty~$, an infinite number of times, there will be values of $x$ that result in one of $\sin(x), \cos(x)$ equaling $(+1)$, the other equaling $(0).$  Similarly, there will be values of $x$ that result in one of $\sin(x), \cos(x)$ equaling $(-1)$, the other equaling $(0).$  As far as I can see, this makes it *game over*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit does not exist. If it would, then for any sequence $x_n$, $f(x_n)$ would tend to the same limit. Choose two different sequences, one for which $\sin x_n=1$, one for which $\sin y_n=-1$, when $x_n,y_n\to\infty$. For both, the cosine term vanishes. Then for the first sequence $f(x_n)\to+\infty$ and $f(y_n)\to -\infty$.

Comment: Even though the limit does not exist, the function $(x^3+x)\sin x+(x^2+x^{1/3}) \cos x$ still behaves as $x^3\sin x+x^2 \cos x$ for sufficiently large $x$. Why does this not constitute a limit? @Andrei

Comment: Just that they have an asymptotic behavior like you described, it does not mean that the function has a limit. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Limits_involving_infinity If you are interested in the asymptotic behavior, then your guess is correct.

Comment: I guess a more constructive question then is: Why does asymptotic behavior $f(x) \sim x^3 \sin x +x^2 \cos x$ not imply that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^3 \sin x +x^2 \cos x} =1$? @Andrei

Comment: You can write your $f(x)$ as $x^2(x\sin x+\cos x)+(x\sin x+\cos x)+(-1+x^{1/3})\cos x$. You can find a sequence where $x\sin x+\cos x=0$, and then the function will behave like $(x^{1/3}-1)\cos x$